# Ranking retrieved data using loop in laravel

Tags: php, loops, laravel-5.1

I have a collection of data `$all_scholar_grade` that hold values of grades. These grades in the second collection are not arranged from the
highest order. This can't be done in ascending order because it is not a query. How do i arrange it or rank from the highest to lowest
using loop or foreach? I tried figuring it out but I can't get the logic.

```
    $all_scholar_id = array();
    $all_scholar_grade = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($card_id as $id) {

        $card = ScholarCard::find($id);
        if ($card->scholar_grade_level == 12) {
            if ($card->scholar_GPA == 100 || $card->scholar_GPA == 99 || $card->scholar_GPA == 98 || $card->scholar_GPA == 97 || $card->scholar_GPA == 96 || $card->scholar_GPA == 95 ) {
             $card_gpa = 1.0;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 94) {
                $card_gpa = 1.1;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 93) {
                $card_gpa = 1.2;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 92) {
                $card_gpa = 1.3;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 91) {
                $card_gpa = 1.4;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 90) {
                $card_gpa = 1.5;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 89) {
                $card_gpa = 1.6;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 88) {
                $card_gpa = 1.7;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 87) {
                $card_gpa = 1.8;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 86) {
                $card_gpa = 1.9;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 85) {
                $card_gpa = 2.0;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 84) {
                $card_gpa = 2.1;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 83) {
                $card_gpa = 2.2;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 82) {
                $card_gpa = 2.3;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 81) {
                $card_gpa = 2.4;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 80) {
                $card_gpa = 2.5;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 79) {
                $card_gpa = 2.6;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 78) {
                $card_gpa = 2.7;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 77) {
                $card_gpa = 2.8;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 76) {
                $card_gpa = 2.9;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 75) {
                $card_gpa = 3.0;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA <= 74) {
                $card_gpa = 5.0;
            }
        }else{
            $card_gpa = $card->scholar_GPA;
        }
        if ($card_gpa >= $scholarship->scholarship_gpa_to || $card_gpa <= $scholarship->scholarship_gpa_from) {
            $all_scholar_grade[] = $card_gpa;

            $all_scholar_id[] = $card->scholar_id;
        }

        $count++;         
    }
```

Output of my dd($all_scholar_id, $all_scholar_grade)

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => 29
  1 => 34
  2 => 35
  3 => 36
]

array:4 [▼
  0 => 1.5
  1 => 2.1
  2 => 1.3
  3 => 1.5
]
```

This is the desired output:

```
array:4 [▼
  1.3 => 35  
  1.5 => 36 
  1.5 => 29 
  2.1 => 34 
]
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of input and desired output?

Comment: @notnull I update my post sir please help me..

Comment: Still don't quiet get this part _These grades in the second collection are not arranged from the highest order. This can't be done in ascending order because it is not a query._